# ng-bootstrap TimePicker spinners outline is visible

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to understand why my ngb-timepicker's spinners outlines are visible,
I suspect it's something with the css but frankly I do not understand enough on this field. A way to fix that would be appreciated. (even if the solution includes hiding it through css, which again I don't understand enough to do on my own)

[image: Only selected spinner's outline is invisible]

Example code:

Html:

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="data.time" ></ngb-timepicker>
</div>
```

css is empty and I only use on TS the regular

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

I'm using both Angular material which imports

```
@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

on styles.css and ng-bootstrap uses bootstrap 4.0 css which imports on index.html, is there a possibility a conflict between them might cause this?

Comment: Please add in code you're using for a mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's likely to do with use of `ngb-timepicker` inside of the material `dialog`. Material is known to not play well with other items. Make sure you have `ViewEncapsulation.none` set, but besides that if you decided to use Material 2 in your Angular project you need to keep to their style guides (which are extensive).

Comment: @Z.Bagley , sadly it didn't do the trick, the result is the same. And I wish that my project would be Material only but sadly they do not have a TimePIcker so I have to improvise.

Comment: It does have buttons and input... you could build a 'time-picker' using pure material items. Did you set the ViewEncapsulation on the root component (app.component.ts)?

Comment: Yes I did and on every other component to make sure, it has no effect.
It's not hard creating it since it's only 4 buttons and 2 inputs, but I want it to be stylish and I have no knowledge on how to do so, (Iv'e already tried using 2 drop down lists for hour and minutes, but I rather something like I posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a bug with the border of buttons in the timepicker when you use bootstrap *4.0.0-beta.2* and ng-bootstrap *1.0.0-beta.5*.

ng-bootstrap only use the class `btn-link` to customize these buttons. It work with bootstrap *4.0.0-beta*, but not with *beta.2*.

There is already a [fix](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pull/1948) which will be available on the next release of ng-bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you! Sure glad it wasn't my fault haha.